# How can I enable NTLM authentication for my .NET Core app running in Docker?

Tags: docker, .net-core, ntlm-authentication, nano-server

I am trying to set up a .NET Core 2.0 web application (WebAPI actually) on the intranet, and I would like to use Single Sign On. This means that I must enable NTLM authentication for my .NET Core app.

This is apparently possible using HttpSys, and seems to work when running elsewhere, but not on the Microsoft Docker image.

Any ideas?